# Optimal way to process each instance on a specified tensor dimension with a neural network

Tags: pytorch

Given that I have the following `torch.tensor()`

```
x
Out[155]: 
tensor([[[[-0.1481],
          [ 1.5345],
          [ 0.3082],
          [ 1.8677],
          [ 0.7515],
          [ 1.2916],
          [ 0.0218],
          [ 0.5606]],

         [[-1.2975],
          [-0.3080],
          [-1.0292],
          [-0.1121],
          [-0.7685],
          [-0.4509],
          [-1.1976],
          [-0.8808]],

         [[-0.7169],
          [ 0.6493],
          [-0.3464],
          [ 0.9199],
          [ 0.0135],
          [ 0.4521],
          [-0.5790],
          [-0.1415]]]], grad_fn=<ThnnConv2DBackward0>)

x.shape
Out[156]: torch.Size([1, 3, 8, 1])
```

where the shape represents `(batch_size, n_channels, h, w)`, I want to process each single instance in the dimension `1` with a neural network in such a way to obtain a new representation with shape

```
torch.Size([1, 32, 8, 1])
```

I had implemented it using a `for` loop (processing each single entry in an iterative way) but I guess this is a pretty silly idea. Instead I think we may only perform the operations in a *global* fashion using matrix multiplications? So shall we do instead

```
mlp.forward(x.transpose(1,3)).transpose(3,1)
```

Comment: Is your model a pure MLP? Your input shape is `(1, 3, 8, 1)`, how are you looking to go to a tensor of shape `(1, 32, 8, 1)`?

Comment: basically each single entry in the 2nd dimension should be processed independently using an MLP. So the input (fixing second dimension) would be 1x1x3 where 3 are the channels.

Comment: This is still very unclear, you mention 3, then 32 channels. Now you have 1x1 spatial dimensions. I think the easiest for us would be to provide a simple example showing the input shape, the shape after tensor manipulation, then the corresponding output shape.